# How to read child of interleaved XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml

We need to update a somewhat old API a customer is using. We're getting the data with simplexml_load_file. The new structure is a bit more complex and I could not find a way to retrieve the new data.

The new structure looks like this:

[image]

Before we used `$ratingPrice = $xml->hotel->ratingPrice;` to get a value.

Now, I need to retrieve `$xml->business->subcategoryRating->subcategoryRating->averageRating`. I'm now stuck with that.

How am I able to get the average rating of wifi, or location and have them outputted in single variables?

Comment: Also, don't forget the `s` on the first `subcategoryRatings`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Comment: @IncredibleHat But how can I access a value directly? Lets say I just want Location, how would I do that? I cannot use [0], [1] etc for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the various ratings into an array and then use the relevant index to process the data your after. This uses the id attribute of the (for example) `<category id="location">` element to use as the index...

```
$ratings = [];
foreach ( $xml->business->subcategoryRatings->subcategoryRating as $rating )    {
    $ratings[(string)$rating->category['id']] = (string)$rating->averageRating;
}

echo $ratings["location"].PHP_EOL;
```

This last line will need to be updated to access the particular element your after.

Answer (score 1):

If the order of your information is always the same (eg. Wi-Fi, Location, Apartment, Cleanliness) then you can do

```
$xml->business->subcategoryRating->subcategoryRating[x]->averageRating
```

so the x is the index of your xml list. Then

```
...subcategoryRating[0]->averageRating
```

corresponds to Wi-Fi and

```
...subcategoryRating[1]->averageRating
```

corresponds to Location and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you could create an xpath expression and use [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php).

That would give you array of [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) objects.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$expression = '//business/subcategoryRatings/subcategoryRating[category[@id="wifi" or @id="location"]]';
foreach($xml->xpath($expression) as $item) {
    $averageRating = (string)$item->averageRating;    
}
```